# ¿Cómo reemplazar las filas impares de una matriz por un vector? en R

Tags: r, matrices

Soy nueva en R. 
Entonces: Dada la matriz A de 10*10 y el vector x de 10 elementos, las filas impares de la matriz A reemplazarlo por x. Imprimir el vector, la matriz inicial y la matriz resultante.
Por ahora, tengo esto, pero el resultado me sale diferente.

```
x <- sample(1:10,size = 10) # Vector x de 10 elementos
A <- matrix(sample(1:100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10) #matriz de 10 * 10 
print(A)
print(x)
A[c(TRUE,FALSE),] <- x
print(A)
```

En lugar que las filas impares sean reemplazadas con el vector x, me da esta salida

```
#Matriz original 
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   42   78   59   30   43   61   20   53   80    63
 [2,]   14   73    9   46   67   40   50   89   83    71
 [3,]   23   93    7   65   62   56   12   31   10    95
 [4,]   87    1   55   72    3  100   17    5   22    47
 [5,]   28   34   97   36   64   91   52   16   86    94
 [6,]   37   21   76   51   92   11   49   44   24    32
 [7,]   39   99   60   70   41    8   54   85   96    98
 [8,]   13   27   90   18   19   84   45   15   58    82
 [9,]   26    4    6   38   57   33   48   68   35    79
[10,]   81   29   69    2   74   77   75   88   25    66

#Vector x 
[1]  2  6  3 10  4  8  9  5  7  1

#Matriz modificada
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   42   78   59   30   43   61   20   53   80    63
 [2,]    2    8    2    8    2    8    2    8    2     8
 [3,]   23   93    7   65   62   56   12   31   10    95
 [4,]    6    9    6    9    6    9    6    9    6     9
 [5,]   28   34   97   36   64   91   52   16   86    94
 [6,]    3    5    3    5    3    5    3    5    3     5
 [7,]   39   99   60   70   41    8   54   85   96    98
 [8,]   10    7   10    7   10    7   10    7   10     7
 [9,]   26    4    6   38   57   33   48   68   35    79
[10,]    4    1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4     1
```

Sé que hay una manera de hacer esto con bucles anidados, pero me gustaría hacerlo sin bucles, ya que a veces eso suele complicar algunas cosas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no esta funcionando por que se le está asignada una matriz un vector. Puede funcionar, crear una matrix con el vectores repetidos del vector que quieres asignar.

```
x <- sample(1:10,size = 10)# Vector x de 10 elementos
A <- matrix(sample(1:100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10) #matriz de 10 * 10 
print(A)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   22   29   79    3   36   87   13   19   18    71
 [2,]   88   61   57   39   20   86   77   53   52     4
 [3,]    8   28   40   78   55   62   82    6   95    38
 [4,]   11   66   24   76   91   69   60   48   65    93
 [5,]    9   73   72   21   30   80   41   84    7    45
 [6,]   67   14    2   75   56  100   12   50   34    54
 [7,]   16   85   32   43   74   89   70   49   90    31
 [8,]   15   83   68   47   42   26    5   37   25    94
 [9,]   44   99    1   17   59   98   92   33   64    46
[10,]   35   10   97   96   81   58   63   27   51    23

print(x)

 [1]  5  4  1  7  2 10  8  9  3  6

 A[c(TRUE,FALSE),] <- matrix(data=rep(x,dim(A[c(TRUE,FALSE),])[1]),
nrow=dim(A[c(TRUE,FALSE),])[1], ncol = 10,byrow = T) #Creas el vector repetidos con x

print(A)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    5    4    1    7    2   10    8    9    3     6
 [2,]   88   61   57   39   20   86   77   53   52     4
 [3,]    5    4    1    7    2   10    8    9    3     6
 [4,]   11   66   24   76   91   69   60   48   65    93
 [5,]    5    4    1    7    2   10    8    9    3     6
 [6,]   67   14    2   75   56  100   12   50   34    54
 [7,]    5    4    1    7    2   10    8    9    3     6
 [8,]   15   83   68   47   42   26    5   37   25    94
 [9,]    5    4    1    7    2   10    8    9    3     6
[10,]   35   10   97   96   81   58   63   27   51    23
```

Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias parece que sí ha funcionado :)

Comment: De nada, es un gusto. Intenta acepta la resuesta (en donde esta la polomita), para que se pueda cerrar la pregunta y no quedé abierta.